# how to integrate a SAS code to send an automatic e-mail?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have two SAS codes 1 and 2, I want to merge the two codes to send an automatic email from SAS, I want to replace the put of the second code (PUT "Code1???????????????? ") by that of the first, I do not know how to do that, can you help me?

````
/**********Code1********/
%macro Controle_QDD (Branche);
data SITMVT&Branche.;
    set Stock&Branche.;
    merge Stock&Branche. (in=A) Base&Branche. (in=B);
    by  &Varlist.
    ;

    if A and not B;
run;
 proc sql noprint;
        select count(*) as NB&Branche.
        from SITMVT&Branche.;
    quit;
    %if NB&Branche. > 0  %then
        %put Le contrôle QDD est OK pour SITMVT&Branche. ;
    %else
        %put Le contrôle est KO pour SITMVT&Branche. Je vous invite à vérifier les résultats en exécutant le code  ;

%mend;
%Controle_QDD(B);
%Controle_QDD(L);

/******Code2********/
filename mymail email FROM= "XXX"
TO=(
"XXX"

)
Cc=("XXX"

)
        TYPE="text/html"
        CONTENT_TYPE="text/html";
DATA _null_;
    FILE mymail
         SUBJECT="Controle QDD ";
    
    PUT 'Bonjour,';
    PUT '<br>';
    PUT '<br>';
    PUT '<br>';

    PUT "Code1???????????????? "; /**** replace by  Code 1 ????****/

    PUT '<br>';
    PUT 'Pour avis :-)';
    PUT '<br>';
    PUT '<br>';
    PUT '<i>Note: ce mail est généré automatiquement, merci de ne pas y répondre.</i> ';
    PUT '<br>';
    PUT '<Cordialement,>';
RUN;

```---------------------------------
````

Comment: To really fix the problem you can either have the macro write separate files.  Or possible just append to the same file. And then in the step that is sending the email incorporate the lines from that file into the email but just reading in the lines and writing them back out again at the appropriate place in the email.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'Code 1' won't work as it is. It looks like you're trying to create a macro variable called NB&Branche in the SQL step, but your existing code is only creating a temporary SQL variable. You need:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select count(*) into :NB&Branche from SITMVT&Branche;
quit;
```

to store the value in to a macro variable. Then your following macro IF statements need to resolve the value of that macro variable like this (note the extra && at the beginning):

```
%if &&NB&Branche > 0  %then
  %put Le contrôle QDD est OK pour SITMVT&Branche. ;
%else
  %put Le contrôle est KO pour SITMVT&Branche. Je vous invite à vérifier les résultats en exécutant le code  ;
```

And you can basically just repeat that part in your 'Code 2':

```
PUT '<br>';

%let branche = B;
%if &&NB&Branche > 0  %then
   PUT "Le contrôle QDD est OK pour SITMVT&Branche.";
%else
   PUT "Le contrôle est KO pour SITMVT&Branche. Je vous invite à vérifier les résultats en exécutant le code";

%let branche = L;
%if &&NB&Branche > 0  %then
   PUT "Le contrôle QDD est OK pour SITMVT&Branche.";
%else
   PUT "Le contrôle est KO pour SITMVT&Branche. Je vous invite à vérifier les résultats en exécutant le code";

PUT '<br>';
PUT 'Pour avis :-)';
```

to conditionally add one message or the other to your email. The whole thing could be made a lot neater - you could save the required message for each 'branche' to a macro variable during 'Code 1', for example - but that should be enough to get it working...

Bon chance!

Comment: thank you for your feedback but there is a problem reading: %let branch = B;
%put &&NB&Branch ==> result: &NBL

Comment: and also I iremarqué in code 1 I'm obliged to put the 0 like this > '0'.

Comment: &&NB&branche resolves to &NBL, and then &NBL should resolve to whatever your row count was, assuming that the PROC SQL 'select into :NBL' worked correctly. Try adding a '%put &&nb&branche;' in your 'Code 1' section just after the PROC SQL to see what the result was; you may also need a '%global nb&branche;' to make the macro variable available to your later code.You'd have to post your full code and the log (with 'options mprint symbolgen' turned on) to be sure what's happening

Comment: I will publish my complete code

Answer (score 1):

So your main issue is the attempt to use %IF in open code.  If you really need that then wrap that code in another macro definition and call that macro.

But since you are running in a DATA step just use normal IF statements instead.

```
DATA _null_;
    FILE mymail
         SUBJECT="Controle QDD"
    ;
    PUT 'Bonjour,'
      / '<br><br><br>'
    ;
    PUT '<br>';
    if &NBB > 0  then PUT
       "Le contrôle QDD est OK pour SITMVTB."
    ;
    else PUT
       "Le contrôle est KO pour SITMVTB. "
       "Je vous invite à vérifier les résultats en exécutant le code"
    ;
    if &NBL > 0  then PUT
       "Le contrôle QDD est OK pour SITMVTL."
    ;
    else PUT 
       "Le contrôle est KO pour SITMVTL. "
       "Je vous invite à vérifier les résultats en exécutant le code"
    ;
    PUT '<br>'
      / 'Pour avis :-)'
      / '<br>'
      / 'Pour avis :-)'
      / '<br>'
      / '<br>'
      / '<i>Note: ce mail est généré automatiquement, '
        'merci de ne pas y répondre.</i>'
      / '<br>'
      / '<Cordialement,>'
   ;
RUN;
```